# HDF5 unable to create file error

Tags: fortran, mpi, hdf5

I work on Fortran code which uses HDF5 libraries for dumping output data. I have been running the code on a supercomputer without any issues. Recently, I tried the code on our local cluster with HDF5 libraries installed on the machine. However, the code runs fine, except on the output part throws the following error.

I have searched this issue on the Internet quite extensively. But, most of the solutions I see are highly specific to their codes. I believe the error is due to some fundamental issue. Can someone explain me, why the error is coming up?

```
15:34:05 -   Dumping OD...
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 522 in H5Fcreate(): unable to create file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5Fint.c line 992 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Mon Dec 12 15:34:05 2016
, name = './Production/od_out_t00000010-0067858932.h5', tent_flags = 13
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: H5FD.c line 993 in H5FD_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: H5FDmpio.c line 1059 in H5FD_mpio_open(): MPI_File_open failed
    major: Internal error (too specific to document in detail)
    minor: Some MPI function failed
  #004: H5FDmpio.c line 1059 in H5FD_mpio_open(): MPI_ERR_FILE: invalid file
    major: Internal error (too specific to document in detail)
    minor: MPI Error String
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 165 in H5Dcreate2(): not a location ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 253 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 460 in H5Dget_space(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 228 in H5Dwrite(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5S.c line 392 in H5Sclose(): not a dataspace
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 415 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 774 in H5Fclose(): not a file ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 604 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5Fint.c line 992 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Mon Dec 12 15:34:05 2016
, name = './Production/od_out_t00000010-0067858932.h5', tent_flags = 1
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: H5FD.c line 993 in H5FD_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: H5FDsec2.c line 339 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file: name = './Production/od_out_t00000010-0067858932.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 1, o_flags = 2
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 340 in H5Dopen2(): not a location
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 253 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 247 in H5Acreate2(): not a location
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 253 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 591 in H5Awrite(): not an attribute
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 1602 in H5Aclose(): not an attribute
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 415 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 774 in H5Fclose(): not a file ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
15:34:05 - Finished dumping HDF5 data.
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to write a file in the chosen location ?

Comment: I just `touch`ed a test file in the same directory of the output. I have necessary write access.

Comment: I just found someone had similar error: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pflotran-users/ZPqqkROX9hc . Third comment in the conversation mentions downgrading from Intel v16 to v15 solved the issue. I also use Intel v16 at the moment. Your opinion on why such thing happens?

Comment: Pixies, probably pixies.

Comment: could you show the code where you open the file? the only substantial info from the wall of text I could see is *No such file or directory* which would indicate wrong open flags (expect existing vs. create vs. append). the second hint is *not a location* in connection with a relative path "./" - change to absolute path and retry; admitted, it is weird that it works on one system and fails on another, but modified open flags or adjusting for current directory could work.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add

```
CALL h5dclose_f(dset_id, ierr)    ! terminate create dataset;
```

for each data writing action. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (meaning, the very same).

The issue was triggered only when running in parallel, when one process was trying to write to the file, but the other was not. The error message is not really helpful, unfortunately. Bottom line: check your synchronisation.